# Is it possible to split a string into an array of strings and remove sections not between delimiters using String.Split or regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I was wanting to split a string with a known delimiter between different parts into an array of strings using a method (e.g. MethodToSplitIntoArray(String toSplit) like in the example below. The values are string values which can have any character except for '{', '}', or ',' so am unable to delimit on any other character. The string can also contain undesired white space at the start and end as the file can be generated from multiple different sources, the desired information will also be inbetween "{" "}" and separated by a comma.

```
String valueCombined = " {value},{value1},{value2} ";

String[] values = MethodToSplitIntoArray(valueCombined);

foreach(String value in values)
{
    //Do something with array
    Label.Text += "\r\nString: " + value;
}
```

Where the label would show:

> String: value
>   String: value1
>   String: value2

My current implementation of splitting method is below. It splits the values but includes any spaces before the first parenthesis and anything between them.

```
private String[] MethodToSplitIntoArray(String toSplit)
{
    return filesPassed.Split(new string[] { "{", "}" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

I though this would separate out the strings between the curly braces and remove the rest of the string, but my output is:

> String:
>   String: value
>   String: ,
>   String: value1
>   String: ,
>   String: value2
>   String:

What am I doing wrong in my split that I'm still getting the string values outside of the parenthesis? Ideally I would like to use regex or String.Split if its possible

For those with similar problems check out [DotNet Perls on splitting](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

Comment: Split on the comma delimiters, and then trim the curly braces and whitespace. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What kind of characters can appear inside the curly brace delimiters? More specifically, can your values (i.e. the text inside a pair of curly braces) include characters that would otherwise be delimiters or ignored (i.e. commas, whitespace)? It's unclear what a good answer would be, given the vagueness of the question so far.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, you are right I should have clarified more. There is a chance that there is white space inside the string which me it can't delimit on string

Comment: What about commas? If whitespace is legal in the value, but not commas, then you can split on commas first, then trim the resulting value (to remove exterior whitespace), then finally remove the first and last character (which at that point should be the curly brace pair, unless you have other non-whitespace characters that could appear outside the curly braces...again, it's not clear from your question what the actual restrictions are on the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that commas are not permitted inside a curly brace pair, and that outside a curly brace pair only commas or whitespace will appear, it seems to me that the most straightforward, easy-to-read way to approach this is to first split on commas, then trim the results of that (to remove whitespace), and then finally to remove the first and last characters (which at that point should only be the curly braces):

```
valuesCombined.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim().Substring(1, s.Length - 2)).ToArray();
```

I believe that including the curly braces in the initial split operation just makes everything harder, and is more likely to break in hard-to-identify ways (i.e. bad data will result in weirder results than if you use something like the above).

Answer (score 1):

Add `,` to delimeters:

```
return filesPassed.Split(new char[] { '{', '}', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: the input string contains leading & trailing white space ` `, and it's not considered as "empty", which would show up in the split result

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are expecting those spaces in the front and end so added some trimming to prevent empty results for those.

```
private String[] MethodToSplitIntoArray(String toSplit)
{
    return toSplit.Trim().Split(new char[] { '{', '}', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Comment: Wont `.Trim()` eliminate the need to call both trims?

Comment: You are correct sir. Thanks for catching my brain fart. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex and linq.

```
return Regex.Split(toSplit, "[.{.}.,]").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of the way to get all the values as u are looking for

```
String valueCombined = " {value},{value1},{value2} ";
String[] values = valueCombined.Split(new string[] { "},{" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int lastVal = values.Count() - 1;
values[0] = values[0].Replace("{", "");
values[lastVal] = values[lastVal].Replace("}", "");
```

What I did here is that splited the string with `"},{"` and then removed `{` from the first array item and `}` from the last array item.

Answer (score 0):

Though very late but can you try this:

```
Regex.Split(" { value},{ value1},{ value2};", @"\s*},{\s*|{\s*|},?;?").Where(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) == false).ToArray()
```